# I get an error: Unable to find column with physical name participationId in table customer

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I try to create two tables using one repository. First table name is *customer*, the second is *participation*.  But I get the error below. It had worked properly before I tried create two tables instead of one.

Maybe I should add any properties to Spring boot configuration or anything to Controller. I added only new fields(with getters and setters) and annotations to Model in order to create the second table.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: 
**Unable to find column with physical name participationId in table customer**
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
at com.jtm.twiservice.Main.main(Main.java:20) [classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with physical name participationId in table customer
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getLogicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1009) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getLogicalColumnName(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:979) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.buildJoinColumn(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:342) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.createPrimaryColumnsToSecondaryTable(EntityBinder.java:745) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder.finalSecondaryTableBinding(EntityBinder.java:714) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SecondaryTableSecondPass.doSecondPass(SecondaryTableSecondPass.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1640) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1605) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1767) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
... 21 common frames omitted
```

My Model:

```
package com.jtm.twiservice.model;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name = "customer")
@SecondaryTable(name ="participation")
public class Customer {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long customerId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String schoolForm;
private String schoolFormType;
private String birthYear;
private String childDescription;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(table = "participation")
private Long participationId;

@Column(table = "participation")
private String participationTest;



public Customer() {} 

public Customer(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String schoolForm, String schoolFormType, String birthYear, String childDescription, String participationTest) {

    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.schoolForm = schoolForm;
    this.schoolFormType = schoolFormType;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
    this.childDescription = childDescription;

    this.participationTest = participationTest;

}

public Long getCustomerId() {
    return customerId;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public String getSchoolForm() {
    return schoolForm;
}

public String getSchoolFormType() {
    return schoolFormType;
}

public String getBirthYear() { return birthYear; }

public String getChildDescription() {
    return childDescription;
}

public void setCustomerId(Long customerId) {
    this.customerId = customerId;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public void setSchoolForm(String schoolForm) {
    this.schoolForm = schoolForm;
}

public void setSchoolFormType(String schoolFormType) {
    this.schoolFormType = schoolFormType;
}

public void setBirthYear(String birthYear) { this.birthYear = birthYear; }

public void setChildDescription(String childDescription) {
    this.childDescription = childDescription;
}


//PARTICIPATION TABLE

public Long getParticipationId() {
    return participationId;
}

public void setParticipationId(Long participationId) {
    this.participationId = participationId;
}

public String getParticipationTest() {
    return participationTest;
}

public void setParticipationTest(String participationTest) {
    this.participationTest = participationTest;
}
}
```

my repository:

```
package com.jtm.twiservice.repository;

import com.jtm.twiservice.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends CrudRepository<Customer, Long>     {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Customer has 2 @Id annotations, which is wrong. Both tables should use same column name, or, if you don't want that, you should specify column in @SecondaryTable( pkJoinColumns) . I think you should try removing participationId field and see if it fixes the problem. Second, it's not clear, what you were trying to accomplish here. One customer can participate in one of what?